# 'int' object is not subscriptable , trying to translate a 2d list to a tkinter canvas, this is the error i got

Tags: python-3.x, list, multidimensional-array

```
def mirror_model_to_ui():
    global screen , width , height , tetris_grid

    screen.delete('all')
    for i in range(height+1):
        for j in range(width+2):
            if tetris_grid[i][j] != 0:
                draw_cell( i , j , tetris_grid[i][j])
```

Comment: height and width are integers, and tetrs_grid is a 2d list, draw cell function helps to draw a rectangle on a tkinter canvas

Comment: this information is not enough to find the problem. at least include the full error and the relevant parts of the code (variable definition, used functions, previous operations on these variables, etc).